# google maps javascript API V3 Pinch-To-Zoom not working in Blackberry Z10 Browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering, if there is a possiblity to make pinch-to-zoom available on some browsers like Blackberry Z10. I tried the simple map example. This is working on Iphone 5, but not on blackberry Z10 browser. Do anyone know why?

Comment: The blackberry browser is not on [the list of supported browsers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport)

Comment: great, thanks! Is there any workaround?

Comment: Use a browser that is supported if one exists for the Blackberry.